# How to create multiple kafka consumer groups in same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

Below is required scenario.

Topic-1 has 6 partitions, now I want to create 3 consumer groups cg1,cg2 and cg3 and map it like this (cg1 - 0,1 ; cg2 - 2,3 ; cg3 - 4,5). How can i create it using kafka-console-consumer.sh or kafka-consumer-groups.sh

Even Kafka documentation explained about this scenario but nowhere mentioned how to do it.
Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to create console consumers in a group?

Comment: That does not work. A consumer group always divides all topic partitions amongst themselves. If you want something else, you need to do manual consumer management.  Where did you see the "Kafka documentation explain this scenario"?

Comment: daniu: i want to create it because i can provide the group id to consumer to other parties where set of consumers will present in a topic (say 2 partitions out of 6) Thilo: its example given in kafka intro doc under consumers assuming p0,p1 and p2,p3 are present in different servers but same topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Kafka Consumer Group** is a collection of consumers who shared the same group id. Consumer Group distributes processing by sharing partitions across consumers.

The diagram below shows a single topic with three partitions and a consumer group with two members. Each partition in the topic is assigned to exactly one member of the group.
[image]

***Note:**  topic with n partition can at max consume by n consumer of Consumer Group with 1 partition per consumer.*

In your case, if you use a consumer group on a topic means all partitions will get assigned to that Consumer group.

But if you are not interested in Consumer Group you can directly assign a partition to each consumer group in that case rebalance will not come in the picture

**I am using Kafka Confluent-kafka 2.6.0-5.1.2:**

```
sh kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --partition 0 --topic abc --group cg1
sh kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --partition 1 --topic abc --group cg1
```

> --partition <Integer: partition> : The partition to consume from Consumption starts from the end of the partition unless '--offset' is
> specified.

Using consumer group you can describe consumer details

```
sh kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server  localhost:9020 --describe --group a
TOPIC    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
abc         0          123           678            0                 -               -               -
abc         1          234           345            0                 -               -               -
```

You can also manually assigned partition through Java as below

```
List<TopicPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
partitions.add(new TopicPartition("abc", 0));
partitions.add(new TopicPartition("abc", 1));
......
new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProperties).assign(partitions);
```

***Note that it isn't possible to mix manual partition assignment (i.e. using assign) with dynamic partition assignment through topic subscription (i.e. using subscribe).***

Ref: [here](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

There are below alternate approaches:

1. Use 3 separate topics to consume messages using a separate consumer group.
2. Programmatically filter partitions while consuming messages.

Comment: With manual partition assignment, why do you still specify a group id? What will that be used for?

Comment: It won't use for rebalance however we can use to describe

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you start one consumer with manual assignment and the other one with automatic group rebalancing (for the same groupId)?

Comment: Actually two parallel consumer group with same name will also get conflict to each other on offset management.

Comment: Well, those are not two parallel groups, that's just one group. Having the same name is what defines group membership.

Comment: it's depend how you are using ....why don't you try by yourself?

Comment: @sun007: its giving me below error with the command you have given
Options group and partition cannot be specified together.

Comment: Also rebalance will happen even if we do manual partitions assignment if consumer consume data from consumer group instead of partitions or during fly we can assign  a strategy.

Comment: requirement is 3 applications write to a topic, so app1 write to partition 0 and 1 and so on, app2 writes to p2 and 3 , app3 writes to p4 and p5... so i need to create CGs of 3 different groups and it should be with in one topic

Comment: umm quite strange i can able to with Kafka 2.3.0 in that case you can try without group id

Comment: if i try without group id its going to consume from the specified paritition, or else if we dont specify partition it will consume from topic one parition by one partition which makes delay

Comment: my kafka version is 2.12-2.3.0

Comment: I am using Confluent-kafka 2.6.0-5.1.2

Comment: ok then no option, i need to create different topic, isn't it ?

Comment: Ideally it should work and i tested with CLI and Java as well..I don't know which language you are going to use ...but programmatically(not through CLI) if you can create 3 consumer group and filter on partition while consuming should work...yes 3 different topic will be also another approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203355/discussion-between-sun007-and-hariram-manohar).

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it out right now, but I think you need to pass it as a consumer property

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer-property group.id=${your_group_id}
```

or if you have a config file

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config ${your_config_file}
```

Comment: this will only assign consumer group for all partitions in a topic